# Jmeter submit post request data form

Tags: java

I want to submit form data in Jmeter which is a post request form but I am unable to do with regular expression extractor. Can you please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Record the submit with Recording controller. (the one with a lot
   of form idFields and values that you typed in while submiting)
2. Copy the request and adjust the data you want to submit in that
   form.

You really don't need a regular expression extractor for that. Extractor is for extracting data from the response, not for posting data.